# Super class of perfect graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Perfect graphs exhibits many nice properties which enables NP complete problems to be solvable in polynomial time.

My question: Are there any result which indicates existence of some superclass of perfect graphs with similar properties ?

Comment: Check out the [ISGCI entry on perfect graphs](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_56.html).

Comment: As far as I know, no such results are known.  Some "nice-ish" superclasses do exist, such as normal graphs, but the best hope may be related classes such as b-perfect graphs, which are not superclasses.  See also http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2503/109 for other "nice" classes you might find useful.

Comment: Although some NP-complete problems such as coloring can be solved in polynomial time for perfect graphs, there are many other problems that are still NP-complete even for very restricted subclasses of it. Every graph class has properties that help solving a particular problem. It depends a lot on the structures of the problem and of the class. I think a proper answer would depend on the problem you are considering.