# NPI-candidate hereditary graph property?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, p-vs-np

A graph property is called **hereditary** if it is closed with respect to deleting vertices. There are many interesting hereditary graph properties. Moreover,  a number of nontrivial general facts are also known about hereditary classes of graphs, see "[Global properties of hereditary classes?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/global-properties-of-hereditary-classes)"

Considering complexity, hereditary graph properties include both polynomial-time decidable and NP-complete ones. We know, however, that there are  a number of natural problems in NP that are candidates for NP-intermediate status, see a nice collection in [Problems Between P and NPC](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc). Among the numerous answers there, however, none of them looks like a hereditary graph property (unless I overlooked something).

> **Question:** Do you know a hereditary graph property that is a candidate for NP-intermediate status? Or else, is there a dichotomy theorem for hereditary graph properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is there a particular style of problem you are looking for, or anything related to a hereditary graph property? Two common types of problems would be
(1) recognition: does a given $G$ have the hereditary property? or
(2) find the largest (induced or not) subgraph $H$ in $G$ having the hereditary property.

As I'm sure you are familiar, (2) is NP-complete (Mihalis Yannakakis: Node- and Edge-Deletion NP-Complete Problems. STOC 1978: 253-264) But I'm not sure if you are specifically only asking about problems of type (1) (recognition problems.)

There are a few recognition problems of hereditary graph classes which are still open. I think the *one-in-one-out* graphs are open to recognize and clearly in NP.

Graphclasses.org also reports that the related class of *opposition graphs* is still open to recognize (and these are also clearly in NP.) Apparently, so is the class of Domination graphs.

A large list of open (and unknown) recognition status can be found on that site, and pretty much all of those properties appear to be hereditary.

http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/problem_Recognition.html

There is one recognition problem they list under GI-complete, which is not a hereditary property ... so it is interesting to think that perhaps deciding a hereditary problem may indeed have a dichotomy theorem.

Comment: On the page you linked, what are the difference between class "open" and class "unkown"?

Comment: @PengZhang I think open problems are ones that have been confirmed open, and the unknown ones are unconfirmed or under-researched.

Comment: This is a nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a finite undirected graph. By a "$k$-independent" (resp. a "$k$-clique") of $G$, I mean a disjoint union of $k$ independent sets of $G$; the maximum size of such a set is denoted by $\alpha_k(G)$ (resp. $\omega_k(G)$). Say that $G$ has the "Greene-Kleitman property" if the sequences $(\alpha_i(G))$ and $(\beta_i(G))$ are increasing and correspond to conjugate partitions. It is known that comparability graphs enjoy the Greene-Kleitman property (see "The Structure of Sperner k-Families" by C. Greene and D.J. Kleitman, J. Comb. Theory, Ser. A 20(1): 41-68, and "Generalizations of the Greene-Kleitman theorem" by S. Fomin, FPSAC'94 problem session).

I have no idea if the Greene-Kleitman graphs give an answer to your question, although I would expect their recognition to be either polynomial or NP-intermediate. Similar to perfect graphs, it seems reasonable to investigate this question for restricted graph classes first: for example, it can be seen that the split graphs having the GK property are exactly the (net,tent)-free graphs. I'm probably missing some of the relevant literature though as I'm not a graph theorist.

Comment: A correction: the GK property as defined is not hereditary. Consider instead the "hereditary Greene-Kleitman" property requiring that each induced subgraph has the GK property. My claim is that the split graphs having the HGK property are exactlly the (net,tent)-free graphs.

Comment: A P5 is in the class of (net,tent)-free graphs, but there is no way the P5 is in split \intersect HGK since it is not split. Do you want to rephrase your claim?